# How exactly work the HandlerExceptionResolver interface in Spring? Can I show an error page when the user try to access to a not mapped resource?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am studying how to handle custom exception in Spring on a tutorial that show me this class named **`ExceptionHandler`** that implement the **`HandlerExceptionResolver`** Spring interface:

```
@Component
public class ExceptionHandler implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception exception) {        
        System.out.println("Spring MVC Exception Handling");
        logger.error("Error: ", exception);     
        return new ModelAndView("error/exception","exception","ExceptionHandler message: " + exception.toString());
    }

}
```

And then, into a controller class of the example, it throws this exception in this way:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/throwRunTimeException", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void throwException() {
     throw new RuntimeException();
  }
```

So I have some doubts about how exactly do this class.

I can't understand if implementing the **`HandlerExceptionResolver`** interface I am declaring a new specific exception type or if simply specify a specific behavior that happens when a generic runtime exception is thrown.

It seems me the second situation...I think that, in the previous example, when a generic **`RuntimeException`** is thrown it return an **exception.jsp** page (and the related message that have to be shown into the model object).

So, if the previous assertion is true, can I use this method for the following pourpose?

I think that when a user try to open an URL that is it not mapped to any controller method a `RuntimeException` is thrown.

So, into the **`resolveException()*`* method, can I extract the required URL from the `HttpServletRequest` request input parameter and use it to show a specific error message (that indicate that this URL not exist) into the returned view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. When the DispatcherServlet can't find the url mapped in one of your controllers, it will throw a NoHandlerFoundException. This will then be forwarded to your servlet container like Tomcat which handles the error and shows the 404 page for example. You can change this behaviour by adding the following to your web.xml:
`

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

`

Note that it's not possible yet to configure this in JavaConfig.

For other Exceptions that are thrown you can use the HandlerExceptionResolver to return the desired view.

You could also use the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation on a method in your controller to catch the exceptions and handle them appropriately. This can be combined with the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to enable this for every controller.